# How to pass argument to command from pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, centos7

I use the `tail` command on apache2 `access_log`, then by piping that output to `cut` I can get the ip address in real time, but then I need to process each line in real time with `iptables`.

I try to do that this way:

```
tail -f access_log | cut -d' ' -f 1 | xargs iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -s
```

But it does not work.

How to call iptables for each line in real time?

Comment: `tail -f access_log | cut -d' ' -f 1 | while read ip; do iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -s $ip; done` _(comment instead of an answer because using `read` for this is a criminal offense in some circles)_

Comment: Oooh thanks, i stoped the ddos :D

Comment: Just hope your own IP doesn't show up in the list

Comment: Try `xargs -L 1 ...`

Comment: @SeanBright no, i use a pre filter using `grep` with the payload.

Comment: You could also remove the `cut` stage of the pipe, and use `while read ip ignored;...` -- that way `read` will put the first field in `$ip` and the rest of the line in `$ignored`.